# Qt creator cannot upload files onto the remote device

Tags: linux, qt-creator, sftp

I have been using the QtCreator to develop qt application for my remote generic Linux device, when i press the 'Run' button, the program will be deployed into the targeted directory on the remote device and running automatically, everything is fine until recently, i just changed lines of code, but haven't change any settings of the project, after that i'm not able to upload the program onto the remote device anymore, in the .pro file:

```
TARGET = Test
target.files = Test
target.path =  /home/root

INSTALLS += target
```

The compile output info shows that:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/root': permission denied
Failed to upload file...
Deploy step failed.
Error while building/deploying project Test
When executing step 'Upload files via SFTP'
```

This is confusing, because i'm not creating the directory but just deploy the program into it, that's what i did before and it worked alright.

I was suspecting maybe i need to update the SFTP to newer version, but based on the fact that i can still manually upload files to the remote device via SFTP without any problems, so i guess this is not the reason.

Is anyone here encountered this issue before? Any suggestions and comments are appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out the problem has nothing to do with ssh or access right.

It is because i have added more than one linux generic devices, but i'm using the kit for the project with selecting the wrong device.

Answer (score 2):

check `/home/root` folders can have rights to access by using command (ls -l)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, that's the first thing i checked, that's not be the reason,  and i'm logging as root with ssh.